# Js как манипулировать объектом .files? (input type=file multiple)

Tags: jquery, upload, html, javascript

Имеем элемент формы, который позволяет пользователю "зачерпнуть" файлы оптом, а не кликать по одному. Подразумевается, что файлы сразу же отправляются на сервер, как только они выбраны (ибо особого смысла не вижу формировать список, а потом ещё раз сабмитить)

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="files[]" />
```

Однако, если мы хотим ограничить пользователя, например, порцией в 10 файлов (допустим, чтобы не перегружать сервер, или если, скажем, у нас на сайте политика 10 файлов в одни руки),  то здесь нас ждёт небольшое разочарование. Или большое.

В HTML5 такая возможность не реализована (или я о ней не знаю). Мы можем указать минимальное количество файлов (то есть - один минимум), а вот максимальное увы.

Получить количество файлов не сложно. Но что потом с этим делать?

```
var collect = document.getElementById('input').files;
//или 
var collect = $("input").files;
// вернет объект
FileList : {
    0,
    1,
    2,
    length: 3,
    item
}
```

Варианты:

- выдать сообщение пользователю, что он превысил лимит порции и прервать загрузку;
- загрузить допустимую порцию и выдать сообщение, что загружена только часть файлов;
- создать остаток "на потом";
- создать общий список,   предложив пользователю сформировать порцию;

Кроме этих терзаний мы имеем чисто технический вопрос: **как "порезать" массив files?**

Метод `splice()` он не понимает. `delete collect.item(i) или  delete collect[i]` на него не действует, в `null` он превращаться не хочет. Создать ещё один инпут (или серию) и "перекачать" в него лимитированное количество файлов мне тоже не удалось.

То есть, остаётся один вариант: грубо оборвать загрузку, вынудив пользователя заново собирать коллекцию.

Comment: С точки зрения юзабилити вы не должны давать выбрать больше 10 файлов. Если пользователь выбрал больше, не давать нажать кнопку отправить. Отбрасывать файлы по количеству - неудачная идея. Пользователь будет думать, что отправились все. А если догадается что не все отправлены, ему будет гораздо сложнее догадаться что он отправил, а что нет. "На потом" поле type="file" вы самостоятельно не заполните, ибо несекьюрно, в любом случае опять выбирать файлы надо будет.

Comment: Солидарен. Собственно этот сценарий я и рассматриваю в качестве основного. 

>> "На потом" поле type="file" вы самостоятельно не заполните, 
>> ибо несекьюрно, 

Догадываюсь что так и есть, но до конца не уверен. Имхо, удалить из массива часть файлов вполне секьюрно: я же ничего туда не добавляю и никак их не использую - исключительно фильтрация по неким признакам.

Comment: Вот подобный вопрос с отличным ответом:
**[Ограничение на количество загруженных файлов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/865482/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)**

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на [JQuery File Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/), там эта проблема как-то решена. Правда, там расширяемость ужасная (мне, к примеру, пришлось половину кода переписать просто чтобы "подружить" с требованиями проекта) - но изучение их реализации точно не повредит.

Answer (score 0):

Просто сделайте чтобы каждый раз при добавлении файла в форме, появлялся новый input, допустим до 10 раз так будет появлятся, после этого выдаётся alert('Максимальное количество файлов 10'), если-же multiple, так-же в jquery проверяем length и если больше 10 делаем e.preventDefault(); с сообщением о том что слишком много файлов

Comment: если javascript отключен, то тогда в теге <noscript>максимальное количество файлов 10</noscript> - вот это ставим

Comment: вы их предупредили, если выберут больше сами виноваты

Comment: >> сделайте чтобы каждый раз при добавлении файла 
>> в форме появлялся новый input

Вот я и говорю *(см. начало вопроса)*, что в случае, когда мы формируем аплоад __поштучно__, мы имеем возможность отказаться от любого файла, имея полную власть над инпутом: его можно удалить, клонировать, положить в дальний ящик итд. 

Но если мы делаем мультивыбор, добавив к инпуту параметр __multiple__, пользователь может выбрать __несколько файлов сразу__, и все они будут помещены в один монолитный железобетонный инпут, который невозможно изменить. Дискриминация, одним словом.

Comment: @Пионэр - file api вас спасет, но не мультибраузерно

Answer (score 0):

Подписываемся на событие `change` и проверяем длину коллекции. Если не устраивает, блокируем отправку формы.

Ну либо отправляем файлы ajax'ом - тогда и количество контролировать можем.