# Почему не получается удалить элемент массива?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть возможность добавлять несколько файлов, как удалить например первый добавленный элемент?

```js
$("#my-input").change(function() {
  var files = $("#my-input")[0].files;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    delete files[0];
    alert(files[i].name);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input type="file" multiple id="my-input">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`files` в вашем случае не массив а объект. И этот объект, по моим сведениям, не подлежит модификации. Возможно вы найдете для себя решение в этом вопросе [Js как манипулировать объектом .files? (input type=file multiple)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/211428/221740)